# Excel Macro- How to set a fixed name to the pivot chart?

Tags: excel, vba

The below is the code that I have used. I want to fix my chart numbers of this and the other charts that I have created so that I can format them later. Also if someone can suggest how to shorten up the code.

```
'Declare Variables
Dim PCache7 As PivotCache
Dim PTable7 As PivotTable


'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache7 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 12), _
TableName:="AnalyticsPivotTable7")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable7 = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 12), TableName:="AnalyticsPivotTable7")

'Insert Row Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AnalyticsPivotTable7").PivotFields("Issue Type")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
End With


'Insert Data Field
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AnalyticsPivotTable7").PivotFields("IncidentID")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 1
        .Function = xlCount
        .NumberFormat = "#,##0"

End With
'Insert Data Field
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AnalyticsPivotTable7").PivotFields("IncidentID")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 2
        .Function = xlCount
        .Calculation = xlPercentOfTotal
        .NumberFormat = "#0.0%"


End With
'Format Pivot Table
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AnalyticsPivotTable7").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AnalyticsPivotTable7").TableStyle2 =    "PivotStyleMedium9"
Range("N4:N16").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AnalyticsPivotTable7").PivotFields("Issue Type"). _
        AutoSort xlDescending, "Count of IncidentID2", ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "AnalyticsPivotTable7").PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(2), 1
```